# Linux bash command "FIND,OPEN,GREP,SEND" - specific question

Tags: linux, shell-script

This is my goal (I haven't made a script yet , this is just an idea):

1. Open some log or file (example: `/opt/log/applications.log`)
2. Find all lines, where is "ERROR (or someone other, what can I find)" - but only today's date (only actual day- example 23.03.2017 00 00 to 23.03.2017 23 59 )
3. If it finds this line, where is "ERROR" (full line, all before and behind) > create file.txt > put in there all lines > send this file by email to example@example.com>

This is my script (not finished yet):

```
#!/bin/bash   

# Store path to commands
LOGGER=/usr/bin/logger
FILE=/opt/app/ebanking/logs/bussines.log

# Store email settings
AEMAIL="eder.marcel@slsp.sk"
ASUB="ERROR LINE - $(hostname)"
AMESS="Warning - errors found on $(hostname) @ $(date). See log file for the details /opt/app/ebanking/logs/error.log"
OK_MESS="OK: NO ERROR Found."
WARN_MESS="ERROR: Error Found."


# Check if $FILE exists or not
if test ! -f "$FILE" 
then   
    echo "Error - $FILE not found or mcelog is not configured for 64 bit Linux systems."
    exit 1
fi

# okay search for errors in file
error.log=$(grep -c -i "ERROR" $FILE)

# error found or not?
if [ $error.log -gt 0 ]
then    # yes error(s) found, let send an email
    echo "$AMESS" | email -s "$ASUB" $AEMAIL
else    # naa, everything looks okay
    echo "$OK_MESS"
fi
```

Comment: Have you done any experimentation yet? If so, what have you already tried?

Comment: If you google "grep log files for errors" you most probably will get a million of results / examples and tutorials. Really.

Comment: Yes, i try write my script, but this script is not finish yet:

Answer (score -1):

`cat $filename | grep ERROR | grep "23\.03\.2017" > file.txt`

I don't know a command line tool for sending an email, just email file.txt normally. You should probably know how basics like using pipes and grep before you try doing that. There are many learning resources.

grep: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1C2Fqjrqgs

find: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peM8bpmTfTE

bash: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html

etc. Just keep reading and learning

Comment: `mutt` is an excellent command-line tool for sending mail (it's the only email client I use). There are many others, including `nmh` and `alpine`